# How to share my Linux home directory with Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, samba, nfs

I have an internal development server running `Debian Testing`. Some times, I find I'd like to do some "on the box" development. I can (have) setup a VNC server and do development that way, but some times I'd rather use the tools available on my `OSX` laptop. So I'd like to share my `home` folder.

I've found lots of tutorials for both Samba and NFS, but none seem to quite encompass what I want to do, and just what I want to do. First question, should I be using NFS or is SMB what all the cool kids are doing now? I've installed both:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo apt-get install nfs-server
```

My naive attempts at getting either to work included

```
# cat /etc/exports
/home/travisg   *(rw)
```

and

```
# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
workgroup = smb
security = share
share modes = yes

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browsable = yes
read only = no
create mode = 0750
```

Followed by either `sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart` or `sudo service samba restart` as appropriate. But neither seem to mount from OSX (unless I'm putting something wrong in there?)

I would love to know which of the two I should use, and a simple example of what I need to turn on in the appropriate conf file and a why? Are there other things I need to install/configure for either of these to work. Really looking for "the simplest thing that could possibly work."

UPDATE:

I got the NFS solution to work by modifying my exports to be:

```
/home/travisg   *(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

Watching `/var/log/syslog` clued me in to the under 1024 port access requests that were coming in. But it seems that this isn't ever going to be truly `rw` access unless I'm willing to modify my home directory with something like `chmod -R 777 *` because the Linux UID is 1000, but the OSX one is is 2139098975. I don't see any mechanism for setting up the connection from OSX so that it accesses as 1000 instead of the osx uid. Am I correct in assuming that there is no way?

Comment: I'd definitely be using NFS as it's native to both OSes, which makes things run a lot smoother. Did you run `exportfs -ra` after modifying the `/etc/exports` file on the Debian box ?

Comment: Can you browse the SMB server using the Mac's network/servers portion of the Finder?  You should be able to reach the top-level of the SMB server, even if your share is not yet working.  You can also specify it like `smb://server-name` (or using the server IP).

Comment: I did run `exports -ra`. When I try to use the Connect to Server option in Finder (Mavericks), I put in nfs://xxx.yyy.zzz.ddd/home/travisg, and I just get a quick "You do not have permission to connect to this server" dialog.

Comment: I've made the changes suggested by MariusMatuliae; as soon as I try to connect to smb://server-name, I am challenged by a username/password dialog. The user account names are the same between osx and linux. Regardless of whether I use my osx password or Linux password, the dialog just shakes its head at me. And guest does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your Samba configuration file is missing the line informing external users where to find the shared directtory: something like

```
 path = /home/travisg/Directory/to/be/shared
```

in the [homes] stanza.
Also,

```
 security = share
```

is now deprecated, you should drop it. You should use instead

```
 security = user
 map to guest = Bad User
```

which is the current equivalent.

But to start testing, I would drop these two statements and first of all try adding, again to the [homes] stanza, the line

```
 guest ok = yes
```